# Setter not assigning value in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to do a temperature program, which outputs the lowest temperature from three cities provided. If the temperature of one of three cities is above + 57 or below -92 all three cities will have set default values which are (+5 Moscow, +20 Hanoi , 30 for Dubai)

However providing those numbers 20,100,35  in readLine doesn't work.
This is how `City` class looks like:

```
class City(val name: String) {
    var degrees: Int = 0
        set(value) {
            field =
            if (value > 57 || -92 > value) {
                when (this.name) {
                    "Dubai" -> 30
                    "Moscow" -> 5
                    "Hanoi" -> 20
                    else -> 0
                }

            } else {
                value
            }
        }}
```

And in my main I have:

```
val first = readLine()!!.toInt()
val second = readLine()!!.toInt()
val third = readLine()!!.toInt()
val firstCity = City("Dubai")
val secondCity = City("Moscow")
val thirdCity = City("Hanoi")
firstCity.degrees = first
secondCity.degrees = second
thirdCity.degrees = third

println(first)
println(second)
println(third)
```

What's wrong in the setter? Why does the `second` doesn't set the default values?

Comment: what are the `int` values you're passing

Comment: I pass 20,100,35.

Comment: So the output should be `[20, 5, 35]` as only Moscow is withing the conditional `value > 57 || -92 > value`

Comment: You are printing `first`, `second`, and `third` which are not even the result of the setter, they are the result of the `readLine()`s. So the problem is the `readLine()`s

Comment: Also note that the short circuit operator `||` is unnecessary here and you should probably just use `or`.

Comment: As @Kraigolas correctly stated, you are simply outputting the wrong values.

Comment: @Kraigolas  I tried  if (value > 57 or  -92 > value ) but it says,type mismatch

Comment: @AdamHeinrich I've noticed there's an unintuitive precedence on the or operator (which makes sense as it is actually an infix function), so I suppose the short-circuit is a nice work around, but you can also try `if ( (value > 57) or (-92 > value) )`. There's nothing wrong with the short circuit here though, it's just unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works as expected to me https://pl.kotl.in/otINdg8E3:

```kotlin
class City(val name: String) {
    var degrees: Int = 0
        set(value) {
            field =
            if (value > 57 || -92 > value) {
                when (this.name) {
                    "Dubai" -> 30
                    "Moscow" -> 5
                    "Hanoi" -> 20
                    else -> 0
                }

            } else {
                value
            }
        }}


fun main() {
    val firstCity = City("Dubai")
    val secondCity = City("Moscow")
    val thirdCity = City("Hanoi")
    firstCity.degrees = 100
    secondCity.degrees = -100
    thirdCity.degrees = 6

    println(firstCity.degrees)  // prints 30
    println(secondCity.degrees) // prints 5
    println(thirdCity.degrees)  // prints 6
}
```

Comment: the output is still incorrect, because one value out of range should have set all three cities,to it's default numbers, which are 20,30, and 5..

Comment: Hanoi, should have 20

Comment: Hanoi does not match the conditional, 6 is less than 57 and more than -92, therefore according to that logic posted it'll just set whatever is passed